# Image Picker is generating only image from Video in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently working with Image picker for flutter. But when I pick video with Image Picker I only get some random .jpg file instead of .mp4 file. What is causing this issue?

```
PickedFile video = await ImagePicker().getVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery,);
```

When I print the Picked file I receive following:

```
I/flutter (25199): File: '/data/user/0/com.example.checkshopsonline/cache/image_picker2738786264491852340.jpg'
```

Am I missing some configuration with ImagePicker?

Comment: So you want to pick video using Imager Picker plugin?

Comment: Yes @SandeepSharma

Comment: It's not possible to pick a video from the image picker plugin.you have to use file picker plugin.

Comment: Yup, I just did that. Actually, I got somewhere about Image Picker picking the videos too. But, it too long time figuring out it wasn't possible.

Comment: why does image_picker plugin has  a pickVideo() method that returns an image?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues, but I downgraded to image_picker: 0.6.2 and it is working well. But be careful the image_picker: ^0.6.7+21 return type is PickedFile but older version is File.

Reference link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52419#issuecomment-723750599